# File downloading giving error when file has %20. (PHP)

Tags: php, download

I know this issue has already been addressed before but those programs had the header function whereas I am using *a href* to enable file download.

The issue is that whenever a file has *%20* in it, it fails to download.

It gives a *404 error* and the file

**For example**: no%love.mp3

gets replaces with no love.mp3

I tried uploading files with %20 in between the filename and when I click on the download link it opens up with a *file not found error*.

There is no issue when I upload files with space in them. They are getting downloaded as it is. The issue only arises with files with %20.

**Code for download:**

```
if ($dir_list = opendir($dir))
{
while(($filename = readdir($dir_list)) != false)
{
if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..') //removing . and .. files
{

?>
<p><a href="<?php echo $dir . '/' . $filename; ?>" target="_blank"> //download link
<?php echo $filename;?></a></p> //displaying the file name
<?php
}
}

closedir($dir_list);
}
```

Please help me with this issue. I thought of using str_replace() but I am not sure where exactly should I use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may not be doing URL decoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It worked using Alfie's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Suresh Koya was about right, except you need to encode it instead.

%20 is considered a space character in the context of a URL, as I'm sure you know.

If your file name contains %20, and you just print it directly like you did, the browser will interpret this to be a space, rather than the literal %20 it is.

For this reason, you need to urlencode() the file name before you print it. This way the %20 will be made to be read as exactly that, and won't swap it for a space.

So, your answer:

`<p><a href="<?php echo $dir . '/' . urlencode($filename); ?>" target="_blank"> //download link
<?php echo $filename;?></a></p> //displaying the file name`

Comment: You're welcome. It is worth listening to Ed's answer too, as I see you are trying. If you urldecode() the file name when you are uploading instead, it will remove those encoded characters for you right away. This will stop you having to urlencode() it every time; it's easy to forget to do this occasionally, if you print it out regularly. But even better is to use a regex pattern or something to strip out anything that isn't a letter or a number from the file name, when uploading.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alfie, I used preg_replace() function and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

**Best solution:** just don't have file names with actual `%20` in them; fix that at upload time. Allowing them is going to give you headaches (and probably means you aren't properly validating file names in other ways, leaving you open to various hacks).

That said, if you must have names with literal `%20` in them, then the URL needs to contain `%2520` (an encoded `%` and literal `20`). You'll want to use `urlencode()` to handle all scenarios correctly when generating the URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Although I used the technique Alfie suggested, can you still tell me how to do that ? I mean validating the file for %20? I am a bit new to php so I am not confident about the method.

Comment: @LazyNinja To be safe, just replace anything that isn't alphanumeric with a dash (`-`). There are lots of clever ways to get hacked if you pass raw strings to the filesystem. You want to pass only the safest possible subset of characters (a-z, 0-9, and -).

Comment: Ok I understood and I will definitely keep this in mind. Thanks a ton.